# What can we do if we cannot delete elements from a C++ container

Tags: c++, stl

I am now using some codes from my colleagues, who created a non-delectable container in C++. The container looks like:

```
NoDeleteContainer<MyObject> objList;
```

With his container, I now create some objects them insider `objList`. What I am now doing is to analyze the features of each object insider `objList`, and if the object's feature fulfill some criteria, I will keep them. Then my problem now is that I do not know what's the best practice to keep them, and there are several solutions I can figure out:

Solution 1:

```
NoDeleteContainer<MyObject*> selObjPointerList;
//selObjPointerList will then keeps the pointer to the selected objects.
```

Solution 2:

```
std::vector indictorVec(objList.size(),false);
   // change the indictor's value to true if its corresponding MyObject fulfill the requirements.
```

Solution 3:

```
std::vector<MyObject*> selObjPointerList；
   // similar to Solution 1
```

Then my question is which solution is best or if you have new solutions, feel free to discuss about them.

Comment: Why don't you ask your colleagues what the point of this container is? If it is designed to hold elements that you are not supposed to delete (whatever that means), it sounds like you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to make a variation on an immutable container is to create a new instance of the container, with just the selected items.

It might help to use a mutable container during the filtering process.

Immutable containers are commonly encountered in certain styles of multithreaded programming.